# Why, while loop is running indefinitely here?

Tags: swift

I am trying to iterate in reverse order but in the while loop it runs indefinitely and print 4...

```
func countDown(start: Int) -> AnyIterator<Int> { 
var i = start
return AnyIterator {
    guard i > 0 else { return nil }
    i -= 1
    return i
    }
}

let  i = 5
while let x = countDown(start: i).next() {
    print("Element x: \(x)" ) // It iterates indefinitely.
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're restarting the iterator all the time in the `while` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function is being invoked everytime and you're creating a new Iterator everytime.

```
let  i = 5
let it = countDown(start: i)
while let x = it.next() {
    print("Element x: \(x)" ) // It no longer iterates indefinitely.
}
```